# ransackを使っての検索機能を追加したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

エラー内容
`undefined method result`
コード
posts_controller.rb

```
def index
    @search = Post.ransack(params[:q])
    @posts = @q.result
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= search_form_for do |f| %>
  <%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :post.content_cont %>
    <%= f.search_field :post.content_cont %>
    <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

progateのWeb開発コース(Ruby on Rails)の続きでやっています

Comment: 具体的な質問が不明なのですが、 index.html.erb の1行目と2行目が被っているのが気になりました。1行目は不要では?

Comment: 情報がやや少なくて回答しづらいです。エラーメッセージはもっとでていませんでしたか？　省略せずに載せていただきたいです。たぶん ``undefined method `result' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`` みたいな感じになっているのと、どのソースコードでエラーが起こったのかの情報が載っているはずです。また、ソースコードもこれだけでしょうか？　コントローラーのコードがこれだけとは思えません。特に `@q` を定義しているコードが無いのが気になっています。質問文は後からでも [edit] できるので、情報を追記してみてください。